# Existence of nested square roots start and end and in between radicals inf

Tags: nested-radicals

Do we have nested square roots with initial and final term and infinite terms in between?
For example $$\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\cdots+\sqrt{3}}}}}$$ which happens in modified Viète nested radical

Or 
nested radicals like general form as follows $$\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+\cdots+\sqrt{b}}}}}$$
 If there are, what is the proof?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If there is a meaning $x$ for it, then $(x^2-2)^2+x^2=4,$ leaving zero relevance to the $\sqrt{3}$ part.

Comment: If what should lay where the sign $(\ldots)$ is, has infinitely many opèrations, I can't figure what is the exact meaning of this. It resembles imaginative expressions by my pupils, when they are asked about the least element in $(0,1)$; some of them say that is $0.0\underbrace{00000000000\ldots0}_{\text{infinitely many zeros}}1$ :)

Answer (score 0):

It has been mention in the comments but the actual value of the infinityth root does not matter, and does not really exist. To that note we may as well say:
$$y=\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+...\sqrt{b}}}}=\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+...\sqrt{a}}}}$$
This can be easily solved by saying:
$$x=\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+...}}$$
$$x=\sqrt{a+x}\Rightarrow x^2-x-a=0$$
Which I believe has the solution:
$$x=\frac{1+\sqrt{4a+1}}{2}$$
Now we can substitute this in to get:
$$y=\sqrt{a-\frac{1+\sqrt{4a+1}}{2}}$$